# expression is not getting binded in asp.net application using angularjs

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I am binding the angular java script expression to bind the simple value i have written in controller function.

here is my webpage code that is created using master page,

```
<div class="dashboard-content-wrap auto-padding" ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="myController">
         <div>
         {{employee.name}}--{{employee.country}}--{{1+2}}
         </div>`enter code here`
```

and given below is js file code,

```
var myApp = angular.module("myModule", [])
                   .controller("myController", function ($scope) {
                       var employee={name:"john",country:"US"};
                       $scope.employee = employee;

                   });
```

i am not able to bind this value in my web page please help?

Comment: i am getting same error, Argument 'myController' is not a function, got undefined

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any problem with your code except a missing div tag.

```
<body>   
    <div class="dashboard-content-wrap auto-padding" ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="myController">
         <div>
         {{1+2}}
         {{employee.name}}--{{employee.country}}--{{1+2}}
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

Please see if [this](https://jsfiddle.net/nagasandeepbondili/d7g0ef40/6/) fiddle helps you.

Comment: actually it is very heavy application i have just commented all the controller function and have written this simple one to check, but in this case also its not working :(  if i use only ng-app and dont mention any controller there then expression {{1+2}} is working..

Comment: Make sure you have included the correct js file. Debug step by step. Please use console.log's. I think there must be some controller or directive syntax error or unmatched parenthesis which is causing the problem. If you can give a fiddle, it will help everyone.

Comment: in console tab there is one error,as i had told earlier "Argument 'myController' is not a function, got undefined".i am not getting why this is coming.can you explain me how to know if controller is being colled or not??

Comment: Remove the complex logic from your controller for testing purpose and see if it's called or not. Thats the way I would do.

Comment: i have already commented all the controller function and have taken a new controller which i am using but still not able to bind..can you tell me if this is happening because of page i am using is using masterpage??